# Will Tunneling help in this scenario?

Tags: tunneling, host

I have a computer running 24 hours at a site protecteed by firewall, this computer call it 'A' can connect to internet but unable to host a site since the port is blocked.

I have an idea to purchase a VPS and host a website there call it 'B', however VPS often comes with low storage size for my files. My idea is when a client browse 'B' website and click a link to download a file, the file will be fetched from computer 'A'

so the case is 
1. Client browse web hosted in VPS (computer 'B')
2. Client request to download a file from 'B'
3. 'B' connect to 'A' via tunneling and get the file from 'A'.

Do you think tunneling can serve this purpose or should is there any other method?

I hope this is related to server things.

Comment: As Lucas notes, it's kind of a shitty setup.  An alternative is to host the static assets on Amazon S3: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html  If your site is entirely static, hosting on S3 may be a less expensive option than the VPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, indeed, do that with a tunnel and ftp the files. Another possibility is a networkshare.

But in my opinion this is a bit of shitty setup. If the connection between your PC and VPS ever drops, your website breaks.

I think you should invest more in a VPS and get a bigger drive, or get some type of external filehosting.

Comment: Hi Lucas, thanks for answering. My website is not really an important site, just for groups of our community, so I prefer cheaper solution.